# How do I map Angular tests/test suites back to JIRA to track them?

Tags: angular, testing, automated-tests, requirements-management, jira-xray

I am struggling how to track my test coverage for an Angular app back to the requirements documentation.  Currently all requirements are pages in Confluence which map to JIRA cases for tractability.  However, I am not sure how to map my angular tests back to the JIRA requirement issue cases?  How do most teams manage their tests to ensure their requirements are tested?

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: I didn't know you can even do that. I can only think of some sort of metamarkers that will popup in coverage report consumed by bamboo or something like that

Comment: @Antoniossss did you down vote this question?  If so can you explain why?  Its perfectly reasonable to ask how Angular developers track their tests back to requirements

Comment: Sure I can expalin - its not me.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing looks like [Requirement Traceability Matrix](https://www.guru99.com/traceability-matrix.html).

> map my angular tests back to the JIRA requirement issue cases

I know such Server add-on, which can do the job - [synapseRT](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/15711/synapsert-jira-qa-test-requirement?hosting=server&tab=installation). It supports:

1. create/link defects & attach artifacts to test execution
2. requirement version, baseline and suite to group related requirements
3. test coverage from requirement & coverage reports
4. integration with Bamboo & Jenkins - Automated Testing
5. requirement traceability matrix

   and more ...

Just keep in mind that it requires a licence.

If Cloud solution is preferred, than I guess the setup will have to include some Test Management Tool, like [Zephyr](https://www.getzephyr.com/insights/end-end-traceability-requirements-atlassian-and-zephyr).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Jira app/plugin that can give you visibility of "requirement coverage". One of such apps is [Xray Test Management for Jira](https://getxray.app).
In Xray you start by creating a user story/requirement as an issue. The respective issue type (e.g. Story, Requirement, Feature) needs to be configured to be handled as a requirement as detailed [here](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Quick+Setup#QuickSetup-ConfigureRequirementsandDefects).

Then from the requirement/user story issue screen you can create test cases to validate/cover it; this, however, would apply more to manual scripted test cases.
In the case of automation, depending on the automation framework you'll be using, you would implement the automated tests code (outside Jira) and submit the results back to Jira/Xray; that would auto-provision Test issues, one per each automated test. These Tests can then be linked (i.e. cover) to existing requirements, allowing you to track coverage right from the respective requirement issue screen.
The requirement/story starts initially by being "UNCOVERED", it gets to "NOTRUN" and finally to "OK" or "NOK"; it's a bit more than this actually, you can see the details [here](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Understanding+coverage+and+the+calculation+of+Test+and+requirement+statuses#UnderstandingcoverageandthecalculationofTestandrequirementstatuses-Requirementstatuses).

Coverage in Xray is multi-dimensional, allowing you to analyze the results from multiple perspectives (e.g. versions, test environments, etc), as detailed [here](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Test+Coverage#TestCoverage-AnalyzingTestCoverage).

Analyzing coverage can be done from a high-level perspective, using the [Overall Requirement Coverage report](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Overall+Requirement+Coverage+Report); this provides a birds-eye perspective of the current status of your project => if you see all your requirements green, you'll know that the related Tests are passing... so in theory, they should be OK.

In Xray docs you may find a [tutorial for AngularJS](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Testing+Angular+apps+using+Protractor+in+JavaScript) that describes the process of submitting automation results.